# mysql: Illegal mix of collations in a store procedure problem

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, collation

I get this error: `Illegal mix of collations (greek_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='` when I call this store procedure of mine:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE setVehicleStats (vehID text, vehStatus text, vehLat double, vehLon double)
BEGIN

    UPDATE vehicles SET st=vehStatus, lat=vehLat, lon=vehLon WHERE id=vehID;

END//
```

although I have **no problem** when I run an UPDATE query directly: `UPDATE vehicles SET st='Καλημέρα' WHERE id='A001';`

I have tried to explicitly declare the charset for each column, etc. The problem seems to occur only when I call the procedure! Any help ?? Thanks...

Comment: why on earth are you using text datatypes for ID and Status - that's a bit EXTREME don't you think ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the collation of the `vehStatus` parameter. It seems the server or the connection default character set is set to `latin1` and the `greek_general_ci` collation uses the `greek` character set (ISO 8859-7).
Try declaring your parameter like this:

```
vehStatus text character set greek
```

Comment: This solved the problem! Thank you. The default character set of the table is set to greek. Which default char set you mean ?

Comment: There is are defaults for the server, for the connection. In this case, I think the one causing the problem is the server default character set.